# Sql server xquery returning element name

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery, xquery-sql

I have the following xml

```
declare @xml xml = '<Values><a>AAA</a><b>BBB</b></Values>';
select @xml.query('for $k in /Values return concat(",@", "=''", $k, "''")')
```

It returns

> ,@='AAABBB'

However I expect

> ,@a='AAA',@b='BBB'

How to write the xquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

```
declare @xml xml = '<Values><a>AAA</a><b>BBB</b></Values>';
select @xml.query('for $k in /Values/* 
    return concat(",@", fn:local-name($k), "=''", $k, "''")')
```